# Add change event handler for custom Container of ExtJS

Tags: events, extjs, extjs4, custom-component

I have created a View by extending `Ext.container.Container` and have given it an `alias` `widget.myCustomView`. Since I'm using it in different places.

The view as usual Ext form components like `textfield`, `dataview`, etc. Now I adding this view into other view using `xtype` as follows:

```
{
    xtype: 'myCustomView',
    itemId: 'myCustomView'
}
```

Now, I want to add `change` event handler such that if any component's `change` is fired, I can fire the `change` event of `myCustom` view. In short, do something like this.

```
{
    xtype: 'myCustomView',
    itemId: 'myCustomView',
    listeners: {
        'change' : function(viewObj, eOpts) {
             //do something
         }
    }
}
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`relayEvents()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-method-relayEvents) method to... well, relay the `change` event from child fields.

Here's some basic code that does that:

```
Ext.define('My.Container', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container'

    ,layout: 'form'

    ,initComponent: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        // i want to support nested containers
        this.parseContainerItems(this);
    }

    ,onItemAdded: function(item) {
        if (item instanceof Ext.Container) {
            this.parseContainerItems(item);
        } else if (item instanceof Ext.form.field.Base) {
            this.relayEvents(item, ['change']);
        }
    }

    ,parseContainerItems: function(ct) {
        if (ct.items) {
            ct.items.each(this.onItemAdded, this);
        }
    }
});
```

### Example usage:

```
Ext.create('My.Container', {
    renderTo: 'ct' // render to a test div
    ,height: 200
    ,width: 200

    ,items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield', name: 'foo', fieldLabel: 'Foo'
    },{
        xtype: 'container'
        ,items: [{
            xtype: 'checkbox', name: 'bar', fieldLabel: 'Bar'
        }]
    }]

    ,listeners: {
        change: function(item, newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log(Ext.String.format('Value of item {0} changed from {1} to {2}', item.name, oldValue, newValue));
        }
    }
});
```

### Going further...

As I've said my implementation is quite rudimentary since it only supports fields that are added to the container by configuration. If you want to make that component flexible, you'll have to handle fields that are added after the component creation.

For that you'll need to watch the `add` event of the container to relay from fields that are added after its creation. The doc says that this event bubbles from child containers, but from my tests it does not :-( So (until that's fixed?) you'll also have to watch the `add` event of child containers.

Here's the updated code for the `parseContainerItems()` method:

```
parseContainerItems: function(ct) {
    ct.on('add', function(me, item) {
        this.onItemAdded(item);
    }, this);

    if (ct.items) {
        ct.items.each(this.onItemAdded, this);
    }
}
```

If you also want to support the possibility of removing fields dynamically, that's when things will go awry... You'd have to implement your own version of `relayEvents()` because, as far as I know, it is not possible to stop relaying events with the one provided by Ext. Then you'd have to watch the `remove` event to remove the listeners you've added to child fields and containers.